# mongoose document can't access property and can't save

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**4.11.2, 4.6.1** two version all tested
node js **v8.1.2** , mongodb **3.2**

```
(async ()=>{

    //配置数据库
    console.log(`configure mongodb ...`);
    mongoManager.init(app);
    mongoManager.connectDB();

    console.log(`load models...`);
    await mongoManager.loadModels(app.conf.dir.db_schemas);

    let dbConnectConfig = app.conf.db.mongodb;
    let uri = `mongodb://${dbConnectConfig.user}:${dbConnectConfig.password}@${dbConnectConfig.server}:${dbConnectConfig.port}/${dbConnectConfig.database}`;
    console.log('uri:', uri);
    mongoose.connect(uri);
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    let userModel = mongoose.model('pub_user', require('./db-schemas/pub/user'), 'pub_user');
    let user = await userModel.findOne();
    console.log('user:',  user.name, user);
})();
```

console print

> user: undefined { _id: 57c38b1573a1951a327b3485,
>         password_hash: 'fc76c4a86c56becc717a88f651264622',
>         type: 'A0001',
>         phone: '13623366688',
>         name: 'root',
>         code: 'root@local',
>         stop_flag: false,
>         system_flag: true,
>         roles: [ '4096' ],
>         status: 1,
>         operated_on: 2016-08-30T02:29:48.246Z,
>         check_in_time: 2016-08-29T01:08:37.327Z,
>         __v: 0 }

the problem is the user.name is undefined;

when I use callback

```
 userModel.findOne().exec((err, user) => {
        "use strict";
       console.log('user:',  user.name, user);
 })
```

still use.name is undefined

the schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import DICT_PUB from '../../pre-defined/dictionary-pub.json';

const PUB06 = DICT_PUB["PUB06"];

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    check_in_time: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    operated_on: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    status: {type: Number, min: 0, max: 1, default: 1},
    code: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 30, index: {unique: true}},
    name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 30},
    phone: {type: String, maxlength: 20, unique: true, index: true},
    type: {type: String, enum: Object.keys(PUB06).slice(1)},
    roles: [String],
    system_flag: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    stop_flag: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    password_hash: String,
    tenantId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true,ref:'pub_tenant'}
}, { strict: false });

userSchema.pre('update', function (next) {
    this.update({}, {$set: {operated_on: new Date()}});
    next();
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log('password_hash:');
    if (!this.password_hash) {
        this.password_hash = ...
    }
    next();
});

export default userSchema;
```

Answer (score 0):

solved
when es6 module `export default` , and need use

```
require('path').default
```

or

```
import schema from 'path';
```